# Integrate Aweber into a Contact form or Contact Form 7 (Wordpress)

Tags: forms, contacts, aweber

I have a contact form with name, email, phone and message. This can work as a regular contact form submitting to my email adreess. But i also want that name, email, and phone to be passed out to my aweber account.

Is that possible using contact form 7 or any other plugins?

The sign-ups form from aweber aren't for delivering messages so i need a way to combine aweber with a contact form.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You can use your Aweber account with contact form 7. Basically, there is two kind of plugins. Free and paid.

[Contact Form 7 AWeber Extension - Free Plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/integrate-contact-form-7-and-aweber/)

[Contact form 7 Aweber Add-on - Paid Plugin](https://codecanyon.net/item/contact-form-7-aweber-addon/8096003)

I used the free one. It worked great.